# click() срабатывает со второго раза

Tags: javascript

```js
$(".rows .cell").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if($(this).parent().hasClass("row-"+ result_2)) {
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
     app.pickMiner(id);
     mine_button = $(this);
  }
  console.log("CELL CLICK");
})
```

Все работает, вме меняется, но иногда меняется только когда по элементу кликнешь дважды. Не так дважды как при double click, а просто с первого раза не срабатывает. Кликнул - ничего не происходит. Чтобы элемент открылся, нужно кликнуть еще раз.

Comment: создайте сниппет, что бы посмотреть что у вас там

Answer (score -1):

После

```
e.preventDefault();
```

добавьте

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: и что будет? *(585 символов осталось)*

Comment: попробуйте - посмотрите.